# Explain how to find the equation of a line given the point (5,3) and it has a y-intercept of 13.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, proof-explanation, slope

Explain how to find the equation of a line with the coordinate (5,3) and the y-intercept being 13.

Comment: you tagged this with linear algebra, did you check what sort of posts usually are with that tag?

Comment: Ah! I apologize, I am new to this website and while I wanted to post a question it said to include 5 tags, I just went random with them.

Comment: @Ally Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Please visit [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). The current question if not updated will be closed or deleted because it does not meet our community standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calculate slope:
$$\frac{13-3}{0-5} = -2$$
use point slope form:
$$y-3=-2(x-5)$$